# External Dual Monitor Setup: Laptop VGA and HDMI, Monitors Dual Link DVI-D and HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

How can I run dual external monitors from my laptop with this setup:

Laptop:

Toshiba Satellite A665-14G
nVidia GeForce GTS 350M
1 HDMI & 1 VGA

Monitors:
Samsung S23A700D (120Hz)
1 HDMI & 1 Dual-link DVI-D

Note: I preferably want to only use the DVI-D inputs on the monitors, because that's the only way to make them work at 120Hz.

Answer (score 0):

You would only be able to make it work at 720p over HDMI, and I'm not sure about VGA.